Problem with expanding folders with asterisk
I'm looking for a way to recursively open folders on Ubuntu 24.04.
I've read here How can I expand all folders while in the list view? that you can do this by pressing *.
However, I can't make it work. Every time I try the search bar opens instead with an asterisk in it. I have tried moving up and down the tree, but it makes no difference.
I realize this is a silly problem, but it would be really helpful if I could easily access the deepest nested folder and see the completely expanded tree.
I guess I'm simply doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.
Thank you!
